# How to use php json_encode options in twig file with json_encode twig function

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am trying to use twig json_encode function but when I do this

```
    var packageDetails =  {{(packageDetails|json_encode)}};
```

and packageDetails is an array of array passed from controller

It gives me error saying

```
    invalid property id
```

because of `&quot;`
so I want to use escape filter;
how do I use it?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Is it simply because you are not wrapping your output in quotes?

```
var variable = '{{{reference}}}';
```

**Update:**

The actual answer to solve the question was adding |raw to the tag as per comments

```
var packageDetails =  {{(packageDetails|json_encode|raw)}};
```

Comment: If i wrap my output in quotes i don't get json objcect.
when i console.log it I get
        `{&quot;college&quot;:....`

Comment: I want my js variable to store an object which i can loop through

Comment: If your string contains a ' sign, the JS will break. Use the "escape('js')" twig filter to avoid that. So, I suggest : 
var variable = '{{reference | json_encode | escape('js') | raw}}';

Comment: Had the same &quot problem, so the | raw comment saved my ass. Thanks!

Comment: @paulgreg Do you really need `| raw` here?

Answer (score 44):

You can add the options in the following way:

```
{{ data|json_encode(constant('JSON_PRETTY_PRINT'))|raw }}
```

Adding this because it answers the question in your title, but it sounds like the raw filter was really what you were looking for.  Still, others may find this useful.

Comment: Isn't dangerous for XSS attack using the raw filter ?

Comment: @Frank6: Depends where `data` came from; if it's from your own database query or similar, it's pretty safe. If it's from user input then it should be sanitized before being passed to the Twig view

Comment: Good ! 
now it's not giving me  Unexpected token in JSON at position error.change JSON.parse('{{ cats|json_encode|raw }}'); with {{ cats|json_encode(constant('JSON_PRETTY_PRINT'))|raw }}

Answer (score 4):

For anyone, who has similar problem with Blade / Laravel5.x

```
var v = JSON.parse('{!! $v !!}');
```

Comment: No use of double {  ?
The variable is $v or is just a parameter. 
Even if not using Laravel or blade the answer isnt clear

Comment: You seriously think I know anything about an answer I gave like 4 years ago? ;)

Comment: Probably not, but that can be answered by anyone who reads this and has Blade / Laravel5.x fresh and in mind.